# List files in one folder structure which aren't in another

Tags: powershell, batch-file, vbscript, cmd

Just got a new phone and have temporarily copied the old ones files onto my PC C:\OldPhone\

On my PC are all my photos, in various folders below D:\Photos.

I want some code to list all the .jpg files below C:\OldPhone\ which are not anywhere below D:\Photos\

Does that make sense? Just to stress, the folder structures are not identical and I don't mind where the file is, just as long as it's there. Filename comparison would do for starters, option to add size would be a bonus!

CMD, VBS or powershell would be good, but anything visual studio can cope with would be ok too.

Comment: have you tried anything already?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

try this:

```
for /r "D:\Photos" %%a in (*.jpg) do set "$%%~na=1"
for %%a in (C:\OldPhone\*.jpg) do if not defined $%%~na echo %%~a not in d:\photos
```

<sub>cmd has *associative arrays*, like *awk*. This doesn't work with file names containing `=`.</sub>

Comment: Batch/CMD does **not** have associative arrays.

Comment: @AnsgarWiechers cmd had this associative arrays long before bash they recently got.

Comment: CMD does not have associative arrays. The closest you can have is the emulation Rob van der Woude described [here](http://www.robvanderwoude.com/battech_array.php).

Comment: @AnsgarWiechers would you please explain qualified, why you deny that there are associative arrays? What is the difference to eg. `awk`? I made a lot scripts in batch and awk, and found no fundamentally difference.

Comment: Please take a look at the [Wikipedia article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Associative_array). What you have in batch/CMD is not a single data structure, but a bunch of individual variables with funny-looking names. There's no add or remove operation, no lookup, and no iterator.

Comment: @AnsgarWiechers thank you for the explanation. Can't help, if you can't see array operations, I do every day (add, remove, make calculations, sort and so on). And I'm really not interested in a ideological, Wikipedia-based discussion.

Comment: @AnsgarWiechers: The funniest thing is that you said that "Batch does not have associative arrays" below a Batch solution that uses an associative array!

Comment: @Aacini It doesn't even use an array, much less an associative array.

Comment: @AnsgarWiechers: I read the Wikipedia article and verified that all features of _associative arrays_ can be used in a Batch file. I can't found the reference that an associative array must be a "single data structure"; for example, a hash table is comprised of several sub-structures. I am sure that anyone that knows about this "abstract data type" (it is called this way in the article) will recognize it in the Batch solution above. If you want not accept that this method use an "associative array", are you suggesting that this Batch program use a new technique that requires a different name?

Comment: @Aacini Please get yourself a good book about data structures and read it. Just because you can make something look somewhat like a duck doesn't actually make it a duck.

Comment: Elegant answer Endoro, thanks. I have included my final code below

Answer (score 2):

This should do the trick in PowerShell"

```
$ht=@{}  # initialize empty hashtable
dir C:\OldPhone\*.jpg -r -file | Foreach {$ht["$($_.Name):$($_.Length)"] = $_.FullName}
dir D:\Photos\*.jpg -r file | Foreach {$ht.Remove("$($_.Name):$($_.Length)")}
$ht  # dump remaining hashtable contents
```

This also takes into account the size of the file in case you have multiple files with the same name.  Ideally, to really ensure their are the same, you would include the MD5 file hash instead of the file length as part of the hashtable `$ht` key for each file. Note that the `-file` parameter is new in PowerShell V3.  You probably don't need it unless you have some folders with `.jpg` as part of their name.

Comment: Good answer too Keith, although I didn't try it. The cmd solution just that bit simpler for me.

Answer (score 0):

```
For /R %%i In (newfiles\*.jpg) Do Call :Check "%%~fi"
GoTo :EOF

:Check
For /R %%i In (existingfiles\*.jpg) Do If /I "%%~nxi"=="%~nx1" GoTo :Found
Echo File %1 doesn't already exist!
GoTo :EOF

:Found
Echo File %1 already exists!
GoTo :EOF
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's what I ended up with, based on Endoro's answer. I really should put the folder locations into variables, but it works now, so that's all I need! I should also put the setlocal ... endlocal lines into a subroutine too.
Now I look at it, OLDFOLDER is a daft name too. This is poor coding!

It copies any missing .jpg or .mp4 files into a folder for ease of copying.

```
echo off
set OLDFOLDER=C:\OldPhone
cls
echo Checking for files in %OLDFOLDER% which aren't in D:\Pictures
del /f /q "D:\Documents\MissingFiles\*"
setlocal
for /r "D:\Photos" %%a in (*.jpg) do set "$%%~nxa=1"
for /r "%OLDFOLDER%" %%a in (*.jpg) do if not defined $%%~nxa copy "%%~a" "D:\Documents\MissingFiles\"
endlocal
setlocal
for /r "D:\Photos" %%a in (*.mp4) do set "$%%~nxa=1"
for /r "%OLDFOLDER%" %%a in (*.mp4) do if not defined $%%~nxa copy "%%~a" "D:\Documents\MissingFiles\"
endlocal
if exist "D:\Documents\MissingFiles\*.*p*" (
  echo Files missing from D:\Photos copied to D:\Documents\MissingFiles\
) else (
  echo There are no files in %OLDFOLDER% which aren't in D:\Photos
)
pause
```

Answer (score -1):

Use fciv (and grep):

```
fciv .\old -r | grep jpg > old.txt
fciv .\new -r | grep jpg > new.txt
```

To get

old.txt

```
6d5f1279d4deccbaeef5d074b13ed2f4 .\old\b\100_1608.jpg
d95e29e2c0172dea438b12c418b09fd3 .\old\b\100_1610.jpg
19f9cda002c951f7a9f870ce74fb1224 .\old\b\100_1601.jpg
32b154f796303a8e9caff0c9d55ba713 .\old\b\100_1600.jpg
26ff43419c4f30764fb015f6d7c869c1 .\old\b\100_1609.jpg
d95e29e2c0172dea438b12c418b09fd3 .\old\a\100_1610.jpg
19f9cda002c951f7a9f870ce74fb1224 .\old\a\100_1601.jpg
32b154f796303a8e9caff0c9d55ba713 .\old\a\100_1600.jpg
```

new.txt

```
545b2121a3af2a8e5aa3c5946b450e87 .\new\c\100_1605.jpg
02a1638739302f3c17253beaa3fe9c1b .\new\c\100_1603.jpg
d95e29e2c0172dea438b12c418b09fd3 .\new\c\100_1610.jpg
19f9cda002c951f7a9f870ce74fb1224 .\new\c\100_1601.jpg
32b154f796303a8e9caff0c9d55ba713 .\new\a\100_1600.jpg
```

use a schema.ini file:

```
[old.txt]
Format=Delimited( )
ColNameHeader=False
Col1=MD5 CHAR
Col2=PATH CHAR

[new.txt]
Format=Delimited( )
ColNameHeader=False
Col1=MD5 CHAR
Col2=PATH CHAR
```

and VBScript:

```
Option Explicit

Dim goFS : Set goFS = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")

Dim oDb : Set oDb = CreateObject("ADODB.Connection")
Dim sCS : sCS     = Join(Array(_
     "Provider=MSDASQL" _
   , "Driver={Microsoft Text Driver (*.txt; *.csv)}" _
   , "DBQ=" & goFS.GetAbsolutePathName("..\data") _
), ";")
Dim sSQL : sSQL   = "SELECT O.* FROM [old.txt] O LEFT JOIN [new.txt] N ON O.MD5 = N.MD5 WHERE N.MD5 IS NULL"
oDb.Open sCS
Dim oRS : Set oRS = oDb.Execute(sSQL)
If Not oRS.EOF Then WScript.Echo oRS.GetString(2, , "|", vbCrLf, "NULL")
oDB.Close
```

output:

```
6d5f1279d4deccbaeef5d074b13ed2f4|.\old\b\100_1608.jpg
26ff43419c4f30764fb015f6d7c869c1|.\old\b\100_1609.jpg
```

**ADDED:**

By using

```
Dim sSQL : sSQL   = "SELECT O.*, N.PATH FROM [old.txt] O INNER JOIN [new.txt] N ON O.MD5 = N.MD5"
```

you could get the duplicates:

```
d95e29e2c0172dea438b12c418b09fd3|.\old\a\100_1610.jpg|.\new\c\100_1610.jpg
d95e29e2c0172dea438b12c418b09fd3|.\old\b\100_1610.jpg|.\new\c\100_1610.jpg
19f9cda002c951f7a9f870ce74fb1224|.\old\a\100_1601.jpg|.\new\c\100_1601.jpg
19f9cda002c951f7a9f870ce74fb1224|.\old\b\100_1601.jpg|.\new\c\100_1601.jpg
32b154f796303a8e9caff0c9d55ba713|.\old\a\100_1600.jpg|.\new\a\100_1600.jpg
32b154f796303a8e9caff0c9d55ba713|.\old\b\100_1600.jpg|.\new\a\100_1600.jpg
```

(cf. [same approach, similar problem](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17721083/603855))